# What is the difference between "start-yarn, start-dfs" with start-all?

Tags: hadoop

What is the difference between "start-yarn, start-dfs" with start-all?

Comment: If you know the answer, then please don't abuse Stackoverflow by creating a dummy post. Find another post you know, and answer that

Answer (score 0):

start-all calls both start-dfs and start-yarn...

Then, those respectively start HDFS and YARN

And what they actually do depends on if you're using Windows or Unix machine, since on Windows, no SSH commands are used to execute commands against the slaves file. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.5/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html#Slaves_File

If not using trusted SSH connections, you should not be using these scripts, as written on that page, and instead use individual daemon commands